# redirect to action after sending email mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, action, response.redirect

I am working.Net MVC application. This Application contains one Form. The idea that after submitting the form three methods have been called:

1. Save data to DB
2. Create PDF File using RDLC
3. Send that PDF File by Email

after all of these steps the application, not RedirectToAction("Message") or any action.

```
    SaveDB(FormCollection collection);
    CreatePDF(nAccidentId);
    SendEmail(string SenderEmail, string SenderName, string Recep, string cc, string email_title, string email_body, int nAccidentId);
    return RedirectToAction("Message");
```

Any Help?

Comment: I would consider sending the email async, by either adding it to a queue to have sent by another job, or using a background worker or other thing...

Comment: @Maged Al Naamani paste your complete action if possible.. and make it sure "Message" action exists in the same controller.

Comment: First I suggest to separate PDF creation and sending email from your action, you can add a message to a queue and do the processing later using a webjob or a service, but thought to try debugging your code to get more information maybe you get timeout or uncaught exception

Comment: @Faraz Yes the "Message" action is in same Controller

Comment: @Milney and Mohmed How can I add these to Queue?

Comment: You would need to create a queue... using either a database (most robust) or a caching layer like redis (faster but potential to lose some if crash) or similar. Then instead of sending email here you just add a record to this queue. Then another program periodically checks the queue and sends the emails...